# Static IP Address for USB Screencast in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, static-ip

My new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ is running the latest Raspbian Stretch OS. I've been trying to connect it over USB to a phone running VNC to act as a remote display.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/), but I've learned that editing /etc/network/interfaces to set static IP addresses no longer works in Raspbian Stretch. Therefore, I tried the other suggestion: adding the following code to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface usb0
static ip_address=192.168.42.42/24
static routers=192.168.42.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.1
```

Unfortunately, this also does not work. When I type `ifconfig` into terminal, the `usb0` interface does not show up. So, my question is: **how do I get this to work?**

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPi Stack Exchange! Up to what point did you follow the instructions in the tutorial? In order to see the `usb0` interface, you must connect your phone to the Raspberry Pi. Here's an old forum post on [how to diagnose the problem with USB cellphone tethering](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6543).

Comment: Thanks for the kind message @David! After a bit of tinkering, I've found that plugging my phone into the RPi & enabling tethering creates a new `eth1` interface. But, I haven't figured out how to do anything with it. Do you have any idea? FYI, running `networkctl` shows that `eth0` is "off and unmanaged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to setup a network connection with the ethernet protocol and using ip addresses. This is made by using network cables for wired connections and WiFi for wireless connections. You cannot use **usb** for network connections with one exception. Only a Raspberry Pi Zero can emulate an ethernet protocol on an usb connection, the so called gadget mode.

But with a RPi 3B+ it isn't possible. You have to configure **WiFi** on the RasPi to connect to your phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Ingo. It appears that you're correct - I've found that plugging my phone into the RPi & enabling tethering creates an `eth1` interface, not `usb0`. But, I still haven't figured out how to do anything with it. Do you have any idea? FYI, running `networkctl` shows that `eth0` is "off and unmanaged".

Comment: @kmeng01 Glad to help you :-) If my answer help you, i would be nice if you could accept it with a tick on tick at the left side. It will finish the question and show that others that it has an answer. For your other question about using **eth0** it is difficult do answer it here. The format of this site isn't made to support it. The best way is to create a new question. There is no limit doing it.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted -- and also created a new follow-up question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96592/raspberry-pi-3-b-to-android-phone-usb-tethering-inactive-eth1-interface). Thanks!

Comment: (^.^)d @kmeng01 I will look at your new question a bit later. I'm just a bit busy now...