# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to Samsung Galaxy S7 USB Tethering Inactive eth1 Interface

Tags: wifi, usb, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, pi-3b+

This is a follow up to [Static IP Address for USB Screencast in Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96550/static-ip-address-for-usb-screencast-in-raspbian-stretch). Concisely, I want to use USB Tethering to connect VNC on my smartphone to the RPi for use as a remote desktop-type connection.

I've found that connecting my Android Phone via USB to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (Raspbian Stretch OS) and enabling Smartphone Tethering creates a new `eth1` interface, as shown in row 4 of my `networkctl` outputs:

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0             ether              no-carrier  unmanaged
  3 wlan0            wlan               routable    unmanaged
  4 eth1             ether              off         unmanaged
```

However, as you can see, `eth1` is "off and unmanaged". I want to be able to give the Raspberry Pi an IP address on the `eth1` connection, so that I can use VNC to control the screen of the RPi via a USB cable. How do I "enable" the eth1 connection and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was the specific Android phone I was using: a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. The `eth1` interface had no MAC address attributed to it; therefore, there was no way for an IP address to be assigned. The final solution is as follows:

First, add the following lines code code to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. This is standard:

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.42.42/24
static routers=192.168.42.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.1
```

Then, run the following commands to give the `eth1` interface a MAC:

```
ip link set dev eth1 down
ip link set dev eth1 address $MAC_ADR
ip link set dev eth1 up
```

where `$MAC_ADR`'s first **three (3)** bytes are consistent with your hardware (check the other `eth0` or `wlan0` interfaces for these bytes), and the rest are random numbers (could be 00:00:00).

That's it! On my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, I could use VNC to remote desktop into the RPi's GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to use USB tethering mode with your Android phone. With a fresh flashed Raspbian image it works out of the box with my Android phone. I don't know what's different to your setup but I will show my setup.

First I connect my smartphone to my RPi 3B+ with an USB cord. It is the only device connected to it. Then I enable **USB-Tethering** in the settings of my phone. Now I will see that the RasPi has an **usb0** interface configured:

```
rpi ~$ ip -4 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.42.236/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**usb0** has got the ip address 192.168.42.236 from the phone. Looking at the routing table I can find the ip address from the phone:

```
rpi ~$ ip route
default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 src 192.168.42.236 metric 204
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.236 metric 204
```

The default gateway 192.168.42.129 is the ip address from the phone. That means all ip packets not belonging to 192.168.42.0/24 will be send to the gateway and it knows where to send them to the internet. This way you will get into the internet. Check it step by step:

```
# Check android phone/gateway
rpi ~$ ping -c3 192.168.42.129
PING 192.168.42.129 (192.168.42.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.42.129: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.709 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.129: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.582 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.42.129: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.341 ms
[..]

# Check internet connection without name resolution
rpi ~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=25.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=23.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=22.1 ms
[..]

# Check internet connection with name resolution
rpi ~$ ping -c3 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.168.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=20.6 ms
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=21.8 ms
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=29.3 ms
[..]
```

Now I'm able to start the internet browser and go to Googles home page by putting this into the browsers address line:

```
https://google.com
```

On the command line you can check html connection with **curl**. Of course you will only see the raw html data because there is no browser:

```
rpi ~$ curl https://google.com
<HTML>
  <HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>301 Moved</H1>
    The document has moved
    <A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Yes, this site has moved and you see this because automatic redirection (as done by the browser) isn't set with this simple **curl** call.

Comment: This is interesting -- thanks for the response. So, you didn't have to do anything to `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`? The `usb0` just simply showed up?

Comment: Whoo, it looks like it finally worked! Apparently, the type of Android phone affects this process significantly... Thanks for your help along the way, @Ingo!

Comment: @kmeng01 If does it help you but doesn't solve the question direct, you may consider to upvote the answer ;-)